# Unable to show error message on form update

Tags: php, wordpress

I've this wordpress front end profile update.. Users can update their password and email front end but when they submit the update it works but it fails to show the error message even though the password are mismatched between the two field or inputting the already existing email.

```
 global $current_user, $wp_roles;

 $error = array();    
  /* If profile was saved, update profile. */
   if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] 
) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

/* Update user password. */
if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => 
    esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
    else
        $error[] = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your 
 password was not updated.', 'profile');
}

/* Update user information. */
if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) )
    wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_url' => esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) ) );
if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) ){
    if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )))
        $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'profile');
    elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )) != $current_user->id )
        $error[] = __('This email is already used by another user.  try a different one.', 'profile');
    else{
        wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
    }
}

if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) )
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );
if ( !empty( $_POST['description'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'description', esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ) );

/* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
if ( count($error) > 0 )  {

    do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
    wp_redirect( get_permalink() );

    exit;
}
```

}

Why is it not displaying the error message I'm unsure of..

Comment: you're not echoing the errors

Answer (score 0):

Echo your $error variable if the expression validates to false. See below.

```
if ( count($error) > 0 )  {

    do_action('edit_user_profile_update', $current_user->ID);
    wp_redirect( get_permalink() );

    exit;
}else{
    echo implode( "<br>", $error );
}
```

Comment: yes i did that but it will still not show up. To make sure that text is not hidden by css elements, I did went through that as well but not really outputting. Not sure where the problem lies.